# Shared dropbox folder access programmatically

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to access publicly shared dropbox folder or file programmatically  with out using app key or app secret,just by using url

Answer (score 1):

If it helps someone  :

**Option to share DropBox folders and access files via URLs by names - with NO NEED TO Share each file**
    e.g.     [image]

**STEP 1 : Create a new folder for your images ( or any other files ) in your PUBLIC Dropbox folder**

```
1. Create a folder in PUBLIC folder (e.g. MyTestFolder)
2. Put an image file in this folder (e.g Grupya_whatsApp_logo.jpg)
```

-

**STEP 2 : Get the USERID of your public Dropbox folder** ( it is the same USERID also for subfolder within PUBLIC )

```
3. Copy public link of Image created in step 2 (e.g Grupya_whatsApp_logo.jpg)
4. Please note syntax will be something like :
```

https://u17835471.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17845471/MyTestFolder/Grupya_whatsApp_logo.jpg

```
5. You May change URL reference to somthing shorter :
```

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17845471/MyTestFolder/Grupya_whatsApp_logo.jpg

-

**STEP 3 : Now - You can create any sub folder under PUBLIC folder and reference to it by using Filenames that are in this directory, directly**
    https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17845471/MyTestFolder/Grupya_whatsApp_logo.jpg
    https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17845471/MyTestFolder/BFly.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to a [Dropbox shared link](https://www.dropbox.com/help/167) for the folder, you can download all of the file content as shown here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

For anything else, you'd need to use the API, which does require an API app, e.g.:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file